# httpurlconnection and special characters

Tags: android

i can send with my app a http post.
Problem is, that the special characters like ä, ö , ... will not be correct.

this is my code:

```
@Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                URL url = new URL("https://xxx");
                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                String urlParameters =  "&name" + name;


                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
                DataOutputStream dStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
                dStream.writeBytes(urlParameters);
                dStream.flush();
                dStream.close();


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                Log.e("-->", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e("-->", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            }
            return null;
        }
```

This http post will send to a php file, which saves the value name into a database.

Example:
The App send the value "Getränke"
Result in the database: "Getr"

where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0):

The internal string representation in Java is always UTF-16.

Every encoding has to be done when strings enter or leave the VM. That means in your case you have to set the encoding when you write the body to the stream.

Try with following:

```
 dStream.writeBytes(urlParameters.getBytes("UTF-8"));
```

Also you may need to set the encoding in your Content-Type header.

Set it to `"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8"`.
 
Currently you are only setting the `Accept-Charset` - this tells the server what to send back.

Comment: i change it to `connection.setRequestProperty("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", "UTF-8");?` but same result. and  `dStream.writeBytes(urlParameters.getBytes("UTF-8"));` do the same

Comment: okay, i found the solution: `dStream.write(urlParameters.getBytes("UTF-8"), 0, urlParameters.getBytes("UTF-8").length);`

Comment: @Stack108 yes you can also do that, it should also work. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may be help to you.

You need to set the encoding in your Content-Type header.

Set it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8`. instead of 
 `Accept-Charset`.

Comment: Why does it look like the Answer of @shriduttkothari.